# Как узнать точное время отправленного запроса и получения ответа в multi curl

Tags: php

Как узнать в какой момент получен ответ на каждый запрос при использовании `multi curl` ? Допустим я отправляю 10 асинхронных запросов с помощью `php` через `multi curl` и хочу узнать точное время - в какой момент был отправлен запрос и получен ответ на каждый из этих 10 запросов с точностью до миллисекунды ?

UPD

Поясню подробнее ситуацию. Я отправляю на сервер 2 запроса через `multi curl` вот так :

```
function multirequest($bodys, $headers) 
{
    $multi = curl_multi_init();
    $handles = []; 
    $htmls = [];

for($i=0; $i<count($bodys);$i++)
{       
    $ch = curl_init('https://...');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bodys[$i]); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers[$i]); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'get_time');
    curl_multi_add_handle($multi, $ch);
    array_push($handles, $ch); 
} 

do {  
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) 
{
    if (curl_multi_select($multi) == -1) 
    {
        usleep(1);
    }
    do
    {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
    }while($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}

foreach($handles as $channel)
{
    $html = curl_multi_getcontent($channel);
    $htmls[] = $html;
    curl_multi_remove_handle($multi, $channel);
}
curl_multi_close($multi);
return $htmls;
}
```

Функция `get_time` печатает время ответа и содержимое :

```
function get_time($ch, $string)
{
    echo "<br>".microtime(false)."<br>".$string."<br>";
}
```

В ответ на оба запроса сервер возвращает свое время с точностью до наносекунды (тестовая функция) и что самое важное время это разнится от нескольких десятых секунд до нескольких секунд, так словно запросы отправляются `multi curl` не асинхронно (без ожидания ответа) а последовательно - т.е. сначало получил ответ на 1 запрос а потом только отправил второй. Разница во времени ответа и в получаемых данных слишком велика и я пытаюсь понять почему это происходит. А для этого нужно точно знать в какой момент `microtime()` отправляется каждый `multi curl` запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете выводить текущее время спомощью данной функции: `echo system('date +%s%N');` (работает только на Linux), иначе используйте функцию `microtime` ([Документация](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)). Если Вы хотите узнать, сколько времени занимает каждая операция: Вы можете перед началом запроса записать значение `microtime` в переменную, а в `callback`'е запроса можно вычислить разность текущего времени в миллисекундах и переменной прошлого времени.

Comment: я знаю эту функцию. каким образом она может быть встроена внутрь мульти курла ? то чтонаписать её до и еще раз после выполнения запроса это не ответ. мне нужно знать конкретно каждый из 10 запросов получил ответ с точностью до микро секунды

Comment: @Сергей а вы документацию смотрели прежде чем минусовать? вам человек дело написал... http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION  в ответе не заметил. буду смотреть.

Comment: В ответе вам написали про callback =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков это еще не ответ. скорее подсказка в какую сторону копать, пока не могу сказать то ли это

Comment: т.е. callback который вызывается в том числе и на 100% загрузки файла это не ответ как узнать момент окончания загрузки файла? логика не понятна.... =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков это не ответ хотя бы потому что я спрашивал про то как узнать время отправки запроса и время получения ответа. к примеру я использовал CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION со ссылкой на функцию распечатывающюу microtime(). для 2х запросов получил такие значения - `0.29194600 1541408973` и `0.30772900 1541408973` это время получения ответа с разницей ~0.016 секунды. но как получить время отправки запроса не ясно.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я дополнил вопрос, что бы было понятно для чего нужно получить время и запроса и ответа.

Comment: @Сергей я бы понял если бы эти вопросы задавал человек с рейтингом до 1к, правда понял бы, но я не понимаю почему вам сложно прочесть документацию, у вас есть callback функции, есть их несколько разных, вы вольны выбирать любую, например CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION будет вызываться при записи заголовков запроса(читай после установки соединения), CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION будет вызываться каждый раз при изменении кол-ва полученых данных.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков про CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION сказано следующее: `Первым параметром является дескриптор cURL, вторым параметром является строка с записываемыми заголовками` Куда записываемыми то - в запрос или в ответ и что вообще значит `записываемыми` ? 
>`будет вызываться каждый раз при изменении кол-ва полученых данных` полученных в один дескриптор или полученный всеми дескрипторами `multi curl` ? Заранее извиняюсь за такие вопросы я `php` мес назад открыл.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков знаю, что наверное уже достал ) но как то странно получается - используя multi curl для 2х и более запросов на сервер они приходят не в том порядке в каком были выставлены на клиенте а в случайном. Они `по дороге` перемешались, как такое вообще может быть ?

Comment: А вам никто не гарантировал порядок получения\отправки запросов..

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков т.е. multi curl может отправить запросы в случайном порядке ?

Comment: Вы прежде чем использовать его не читали документацию? вот цитата с php.net `Пример #1 Пример использования curl_multi_exec()` ..... `а затем запустит их асинхронно.` **Асинхронно** - значит без ожидания какого либо ответа, читай параллельно, читай в разных потоках, читай `очередность исполнения будет зависить от ОС, железа и кучи прочих параметров`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков `без ожидания какого либо ответа` не означает `в разных потоках`. Про  потоки в мануале как раз ни слова. php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php.

Comment: Учите матчасть, то что у вас выделено - истиная правда, но так же это во первых не значит обратного, во вторых сеть это такая штука где даже отправляя все данные по порядку можно запросто получить на принимающей стороне их в ином порядке, и исправлением вот таких вот красот занимается например протокол TCP, причем в пределах одного соединения а не всех разом.... =) и никто не гарантирует что 2 параллельных соединения во первых установятся с первой попытки, во вторых согласуются именно в том порядке в котором были иницированы...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков огромное спасибо, действительно в СП очень много нюансов. Жаль не знаю пока способа точно определить момент времени когда запрос дошел до сервера если такой способ существует, буду закрывать пробелы в теории)

Comment: В windows - только на уровне драйвера ядра

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в данном случае у меня linux. К сожалению заголовок DATE согласно 3.3.1 пункту спецификации HTTP возвращает дату до секунды когда сообщение было создано, что никак не поможет понять какой запрос пришел раньше.